# rails: organizing data into a table using for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, for-loop

I have the following view:

```
<table class="fixed">                                                                            
  <tr>                                                                             
    <th>Student Name</th>
    <!-- create as many <th> as there are evaluations -->
    <% @eval_count.times do |i|  %>                                                 
      <th>Evaluation <%= i+1 %></th>
    <% end %>    
    <th>Student Average <br />(for this goal)</th>

  </tr>                                                                           

  <% for eval in @evals %>                     
    <tr class="<%= cycle("odd", "even", name: "evals")%>">
        <!-- eval returns { s_id [eval],[eval]} -->
      <td><%= eval[1].first.student.name%></td> 
      <!-- in each student's row, print the score for each consecutive evaluation -->
      <% @eval_count.times do |i|  %>                                                 
        <td><%= eval[1][i].score %><% @ss_scores << eval[1][i].score %></td> 
      <% end %>
      <td><%= @ss_scores %></td>
    </tr>             
   <% reset_cycle("evals") %>   
   <% end %>                                                                        
</table>

<% @ss_scores.in_groups(@student_count, false) do |group|%>
    <%= (group.sum.to_f/group.size).round(2) %>                                                    
<% end %>
```

which renders the following:

[image]

I want to put the average for each student in the last column, but `@ss_scores` is a variable and so calling anything on it doesn't work. But when the `for` loop has finished, `@ss_scores` can be worked with nicely as in the bottom of the screenshot. Any idea how to do this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try emptying the array everytime, using [] and calculate the average inline, like below**

```
 <td><%= @ss_scores.inject(0.0) { |sum, el| sum + el } / @ss_scores.size %></td>
 <% @ss_scores = [] %>
```

-

```
<% for eval in @evals %>                      
        <tr class="<%= cycle("odd", "even", name: "evals")%>">
            <!-- eval returns { s_id [eval],[eval]} -->
          <td><%= eval[1].first.student.name%></td> 
          <!-- in each student's row, print the score for each consecutive evaluation -->
          <% @eval_count.times do |i|  %>                                                 
            <td><%= eval[1][i].score %>
              <% @ss_scores << eval[1][i].score %>
            </td> 
          <% end %>
          <td><%= @ss_scores.inject(0.0) { |sum, el| sum + el } / @ss_scores.size %></td>
          <% @ss_scores = [] %>
        </tr>             
       <% reset_cycle("evals") %>  

    <% end %>
```

Comment: Ah!!  I actually had `@ss_scores.clear` in here at one point, not sure how i missed that.  Thanks though!

Comment: Cool, try and change this attitude from your next app development.."(please don't point out that it's not good to have logic in views)"...Just for your good!

Comment: actually it got edited and it kind of reads differently - i meant to say that i'm only doing this while trying to make the code work and will refactor later - but point taken, and thanks again